# There is no cookie at all in my Next.Js frontend

Tags: django, next.js

I made Django Backend. and Next.js Frontend. There is cookie which has _ga, csrftoken when I tested on local server 127.0.0.1.

[image]

BUT, there is no cookie at all on my production (which has different domain backend and frontend).

[image]

I guessed that everything happened because I used different domain when production. Here is some django settings.py I have

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "127.0.0.1",
    "localhost",
    "BACKENDURL",
    "FRONTENDURL",
    "*.FRONTENDURL",
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "https://*.frontendURL",
    "https://FRONTENDURL",
]
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future visitors...

I figured out what I was wrong.

In Development Settings, 
I use same domain  
[127.0.0.1:3000] as frontend (Next.JS) 
[127.0.0.1:8000] as backend (Django) 

But, In Production Settings, 
I use different domain 
[frontend.com] as frontend 
[backend.com] as backend 
Which leads "cross-site" error on request/response.

I also found that there is no cookie in my production 
due to I use different domain in production 
Different domain cannot use same cookie => No Cookie on the frontend.

Thus, I have to set the domain same on backend and frontend in 'hosting service site' 
www -> frontendurl 
backend -> backendurl 
=> Then I can get the csrftoken and sessionid when login. 

Also, I made my settings.py in django project including...

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".mydomain"
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".mydomain"
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

I recognize that CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS leads some danger... 
I set it just to confirm that everything is fine. 
Later on, In production, change it into

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [...]
```

Hope my answer helped someone. 
Happy Hacking my friends. Good Luck!